# Tor connecting to HTTP

Tags: https, kali-linux

I need Tor to connect to my adult website "test11.easyxtubes.com". For some reason it will not connect as it is HTTP. It seems all tor traffic HTTPS. My question is how can I force tor to connect to my HTTP website. If I need to alter torcc please provide me an example.

My OS is Kali Linux 2.0

Comment: Disabling HTTPS will mean your traffic is unencrypted at certain points in the circuit. If you're using Tor for reasons of anonymity, then that probably isn't what you want.

Comment: Do you have any indication that this is related to http vs. https? That seems unlikely. Without any more information, it is much more likely that the site or hosting provider blocks traffic from Tor exit nodes.

Answer (score 2):

This can have several reasons:

1. Tor Browser comes with HTTPS Everywhere. This addon has rules for several sites to connect via HTTPS. At https://atlas.eff.org/index.html?tubes you can see all sites which contain *tubes*. Your site is not among them.
2. There is a chance that the site itself redirects your request to the HTTPS. You can check it with `curl`. Just enter `curl -I your-site.example.com`. Look at the first line and the line with the `Location:` header. When there is a redirect you see `HTTP/1.1 301` or some other `3XX` number. The `Location:` tells you the target of the redirect.
3. It also might be the case that the site has a HSTS header. So when you visited the site before via HTTPS and the HSTS header is set, your browser will always try to visit the site over HTTPS again. You can also check it via `curl`.